# Run for loop for multiple folders

Tags: linux, bash, for

I have  been working with multiple folders, each folder have distinct name and each of them have multiple CSV files inside, i have a bash script that for each csv file inside the folder, makes a folder with the name of the file and makes N copies of the files inside the new folder, in the original bash script, i can write the specifically folder were it runs.

But now, i have a hundred of folders, and i try to automatize this script but it don't works appropriately

```
#cd grupo_2_pareja_D-H
#cd grupo_2_single_D-H
#cd grupo_2_tercia_CDH
for d in ./*; do
    echo "$d"
    for x in ./* .csv; do
        mkdir "${x%.*}" 
        for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do # Create a loop, looping N times
        cp "$x" "${x%.*}/"${x%.*}"_$i.csv" # use i in the copy command
        #rm -f "$x" # Remove the file after the N copies
        done
    done  
done
```

I looking for some help to make this posible, thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: What if you simplified your example to write **one** script that could correctly process **one** directory?  Try to get that working first, and then hey, you can just call that script `N` times, once for each of your `N` directories.

Comment: thanks mate, i think is a practical solution, but in really, i try thinking in a one touch solution.

Comment: Well, it's much like learning to walk first, and then you learn to run.  You simply cannot do N directories correctly until you can do **1** directory correctly.  Perhaps if you can [edit] your post to indicate what error you are having, others here can assist.

Comment: Try changing the second `for` to `for x in "$d"/*.csv; do` and see if that gets you closer.

Comment: It works, but now, the new folders created are empty

Comment: Try putting an echo on the `cp` command to see what it’s doing, presumably this was throwing an error? I think you’re going to have to work on how you build the target file name.

Comment: it's correct, i got an error about `stat' ' ./*.csv' file don't exist, i'm gonna try to solve it, thanks for all to

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: loop over directories `./*/` only (trailing slash). `for` loop always should handle unresolved globs. add line `[ -f "$x" ] || continue;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `find`? I don't think my script will be faster, but it kinda works. `-execdir` need gnu find but with a little bit tweaks, POSIX find with `-exec` may also work.

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" -type f -name '*.csv' -execdir sh -c 'name="${1%.csv}"; mkdir -- "$name"; for i in $(seq 10); do cp -- "$1" "$name/${name}_$i.csv" & done' shell '{}' \;
```

Comment: This is cool, it works and it's really useful, thank you mate